# Laravel 5 storage permission

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can we set folder permission when we create make directory using Laravel 5 storage?

```
Storage::makeDirectory($encrypt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the second parameter `$mode`

```
public function makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0755, $recursive = false, $force = false)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the file location of makeDirectory function.

Comment: No problem. File is located here `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:322`

Comment: So it affects all folders. If some directory has another permission type. Can we use Storage::makeDirectory($encrypt, 0777);

Comment: Try using `Storage::makeDirectory($encrypt, 0777, false);` to make sure it's not recursive. It's `false` by default but you're probably going through a few other classes before it gets to this method which may be defaulting it to `true`. I haven't tested this, just a guess.

Comment: You're welcome. If I answered your question, voting it as your correct answer would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$encrypt` is a path

```
Storage::makeDirectory($encrypt, $mode = 0755);
```